# Mass records update based on changed locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a Rails app where a user gets to choose default or custom email content. If user writes his own content, the default one gets overwritten by the custom content.

The app has many users and most of them have not defined their custom content. So far, the default content was just a draft and recently I've changed it to a new one in locales.

Unfortunately, only new users can use the new default content out of the box after they register. Older users still have the draft. I would like to perform a batch update on the users so that they also have a new default content of messages.

The code is as follows:

The service defines whether the email is customized or default:

```
class CreateEmailMessage
  def call(job)
    job.custom_email_message || job.job_message_template.email_body
  end
end
```

The method below defines which template should be used:

```
def job_message_template
  job_message_templates.public_send(severity_key)
end
```

Because the templates are defined in a hash:

```
DEFAULT_VIDEO_MESSAGE_TEMPLATES = {
  "low"    => {
    "text_body"     => I18n.t("locale1"),
    "email_subject" => I18n.t("locale2"),
    "email_body"    => I18n.t("locale3")
  },
  "medium" => {
    "text_body"     => I18n.t("locale4"),
    "email_subject" => I18n.t("locale5"),
    "email_body"    => I18n.t("locale6")
  },
  "high"   => {
    "text_body"     => I18n.t("locale7"),
    "email_subject" => I18n.t("locale8"),
    "email_body"    => I18n.t("locale9")
  },
  "thank_you"         => {
    "text_body"       => I18n.t("locale10"),
    "email_subject"   => I18n.t("locale11"),
    "email_body"      => I18n.t("locale12")
  },
  "additional_work"   => {
    "text_body"       => I18n.t("locale13"),
    "email_subject"   => I18n.t("locale14"),
    "email_body"      => I18n.t("locale15")
  }
}.freeze
```

To sum up, I want to perform mass update of `user.job_message_template` so that they use the new predefined templates if they do not have their own custom message.

I will be extremely grateful for help!

Comment: So whats the question? How to perform mass update? Or you are looking for a better approach?

Comment: Yes, I want to perform a mass update of the old records so that they fetch new locale from `en.yml`. What's the best approach to that @MartinZinovsky?